# How can we find server location and IPs?

Tags: webserver, server, geolocation

Is it possible to find where some known application servers (such as whatsapp) are located and their IPs ?

Comment: Probably too broad to answer: in general, you can't even determine which servers are the application ones and which are gateways, load balancers, proxies, etc. on the same network. Then you get complications from single IP addresses which relate to multiple servers (e.g. anycast)...

Comment: All traffic to the servers can be monitored to determine the IP. IPs can be loosely located.

Comment: @schroeder, do you mean that's its just the destination ip in the outgoing packets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to know the *IP address* of the host your application is communicating with.  This is, as you comment, just the destination IP of the communications.

But knowing that IP address doesn't get you much. There is no way of knowing if that host is a web server/other server, a gateway or proxy, a network load balancer or content distribution network node. It might be, and often is, multiple hosts. It might be one IP today, and another IP tomorrow; or one set of IP's for the US West Coast, and another set for the US East Coast. Content Distribution Networks have changed the way we deliver content from servers - most app services of any size have large distributed networks of content making up what you'd call a "server". All you know from the IP is the peer that your client is communicating with, and nothing about what kind of architecture is hiding behind it.

Location is yet another problem. Geolocation is inexact, and [sometimes very inexact](https://splinternews.com/how-an-internet-mapping-glitch-turned-a-random-kansas-f-1793856052). You *might* be able to tell what country an IP is coming from, or at least what region of the world. It depends on what information the ISP's are revealing, how dynamic the network is, whether measures are being taken to conceal location, etc.

In short, the answer is "sometimes, maybe, but don't depend on it".